# Calculate the reliability polynomial of $K_5$

Tags: graph-theory

The way that I understand the reliability polynomial is that we can look at each edge as having a potential to fail with p probability. This means it won't fail at 1-p probability. For example with a tree, if any edge fails then it becomes disconnected so then the reliability polynomial for trees is $(1-p)^n$ for a tree with $n$ edges.

What I don't understand using this approach is how would I do it with a graph such as $K_5$. If 4 edges fail, then it is possible for it to be disconnected, but it is also possible that it doesn't become disconnected if certain edges fail.

Additionally, I've read that the Tutte polynomial has a relation to the reliability polynomial, but I am not sure how to use it to calculate the reliability polynomial.

Comment: Both [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReliabilityPolynomial.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial#Reliability_polynomial) show how to obtain the reliability polynomial in terms of the Tutte polynomial.